# Error: Type '() => Promise<{}[]>' is not assignable to type '{}[]'. How do I fix this in DrizzleORM?

Tags: database, next.js, drizzle

Hi I am using DrizzleORM with Neon as DB on Nextjs. The error: ***Type '() => Promise<{ deptno: string; deptname: string; mgrno: string | null; topdep: boolean | null; admrdept: string; location: string | null; }[]>' is not assignable to type '{ deptno: string; deptname: string; mgrno: string | null; topdep: boolean | null; admrdept: string; location: string | null; }[]'.*** I have tried my best to deal with it and find solution but, nothing removed it. Please let me know if I have to add some other library or if there is something wrong with my code. Also, I have tried using ServerSideProps and do the same thing using that and there too the same error occurred. Thanks!

```
import { pgTable, pgEnum, pgSchema, AnyPgColumn, uuid, varchar, boolean, char, foreignKey, date, integer, smallint } from "drizzle-orm/pg-core"
import { neon, neonConfig } from '@neondatabase/serverless'
import { drizzle } from 'drizzle-orm/neon-http';
import { InferModel, sql as localSql } from 'drizzle-orm';

export const department = pgTable("department", {
    deptno: uuid("deptno").default(localSql`uuid_generate_v4()`).primaryKey().notNull(),
    deptname: varchar("deptname", { length: 36 }).notNull(),
    mgrno: uuid("mgrno"),
    topdep: boolean("topdep"),
    admrdept: uuid("admrdept").notNull(),
    location: char("location", { length: 16 }),
});

export const employee = pgTable("employee", {
    empno: uuid("empno").default(localSql`uuid_generate_v4()`).primaryKey().notNull(),
    empname: varchar("empname", { length: 26 }).notNull(),
    sex: char("sex", { length: 1 }),
    email: varchar("email", { length: 26 }),
    phone: char("phone", { length: 10 }).notNull(),
    dob: date("dob"),
    departmentid: uuid("departmentid").references(() => department.deptno, { onDelete: "set null" }),
    subordinateto: uuid("subordinateto"),
    job: char("job", { length: 8 }),
    salary: integer("salary"),
    experience: smallint("experience"),
    hiredate: date("hiredate").default(localSql`CURRENT_DATE`).notNull(),
});

export type Department = InferModel<typeof department>
export type Employee = InferModel<typeof employee>

neonConfig.fetchConnectionCache = true;

const sql = neon(process.env.DATABASE_URL as string);
const db = drizzle(sql);

export const allDepartments: Department[] = async () => { return await db.select().from(department) }   //Type '() => Promise<{ deptno: string; deptname: string; mgrno: string | null; topdep: boolean | null; admrdept: string; location: string | null; }[]>' is not assignable to type '{ deptno: string; deptname: string; mgrno: string | null; topdep: boolean | null; admrdept: string; location: string | null; }[]'.
```